# Exceeded maximum execution time in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an Apps Script that constantly gets this error. Judge by the notification email, it looks like the time limit is 5 minutes. Does anyone know if there is a way to extend this time limit? Or perhaps is there a way to call the Apps Script again and it pick up from where it left off? Any help is appreciated.