# Meaning of Trigger Aggregate Execution Time in Apps Script dashboard quota limits?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, quota

My code will process data in batches as recommended in this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/exceeded-maximum-execution-time-in-google-apps-script) and I wanted
to get a clarification of the  meaning of "Trigger Aggregate Execution Time" on the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard)

Does "Trigger Aggregate Execution Time" refer to the *aggregate total runtime of triggered events and user run functions*(by user run function i.e. I select Run->myFunction in the development environment) or total runtime of *explicitly set triggered events* as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events)?

Does selecting Run->myFunction in the development environment contribute to the "Trigger Aggregate Execution Time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trigger Aggregate Execution Time is the total execution time for functions that were invoked from triggers. So, if you run a function from within the Script Editor, it will not contribute toward that limit, but if it was run based off of a time-based trigger, an onOpen trigger, etc. then it will contribute toward the limit.