# Hitting a maximum execution error on google mail apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

This script saves the relevant emails I need from an inbox, but due to the size of the inbox I keep getting a timeout from google "Max execution time" error. As the script is taking longer than the 5 mins allowed. It works perfectly on a smaller inbox.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:League Full";


function getEmails_(q) {


    var output = [];


    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);


    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();




        for (var j in msgs) {
            output.push([msgs[j].getSubject(),msgs[j].getFrom(),msgs[j].getDate()]);
        }


    }
    return output;
}



function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}



function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY,1,100);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}
```

I've found a script which I think may work online but I'm struggling to implement it, does anyone have any experience with ScriptProperties that could point me in the right direction?

```
function runMe() {
  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();

saveEmails();

  var startRow = ScriptProperties.getProperty("start_row");
  for(var ii = startRow; ii <= size; ii++) {
    var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
      ScriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", ii)
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("runMe")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime+300000))
               .create();
      break;
    } else {
  saveEmails();
    }
  }

  //do some more work here

}
```

Comment: Please see this link: [Exceeded Maximum Execution Time In Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/exceeded-maximum-execution-time-in-google-apps-script?rq=1)

Comment: Hi I tried that, if you see the code its the same but I couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions? 

I've added in the time (5 mins worth of milliseconds) and I've added in the function. @Br.Sayan

Comment: Well, please insert a `Logger.log()` for checking `currTime - startTime` before the `if` statement `if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME)`. Now you `MAX_RUNNING_TIME` contains nothing. Put the `Maximum(currTime - startTime)` value there. I think it should be ~ 360 secs.

Comment: I'm sorry, Google says `ScriptProperties API is deprecated.` So we need to find another way out.

Answer (score 1):

As `ScriptProperties` has been deprecated by Google, the above script should not work. As mentioned by Sujay, we should use the Properties Service instead. The following script is working fine.

```
    function runMe() {

  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
  for(var ii = startRow; ii <= 300000; ii++) {
    var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    Logger.log(currTime - startTime);

    if(currTime - startTime > 300000) {
      Logger.log("Inside Loop :" + currTime);
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", ii);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("runMe")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime + 300000))
               .create();
      break;
    } else {
      doSomeWork();
      Logger.log("Running on : " + new Date(currTime));
    }
  }

 Logger.log("Do some more work...");

}
```

The Execution Transcript entries are as follows:

```
[16-02-25 09:53:12:326 IST] Logger.log([300000.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:327 IST] Logger.log([Running on : Thu Feb 25 2016 09:53:12 GMT+0530 (IST), []]) [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:328 IST] Logger.log([300001.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:329 IST] Logger.log([Inside Loop :1456374192327, []]) [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:361 IST] Properties.setProperty([start_row, 173281.0]) [0.031 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:362 IST] ScriptApp.newTrigger([runMe]) [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:363 IST] TriggerBuilder.timeBased() [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:365 IST] ClockTriggerBuilder.at([Wed Feb 24 20:28:12 PST 2016]) [0.002 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:623 IST] ClockTriggerBuilder.create() [0.257 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:624 IST] Logger.log([Do some more work..., []]) [0 seconds]
[16-02-25 09:53:12:626 IST] Execution succeeded [10.298 seconds total runtime]
```

Don't get confused with the Trigger time, it is set at PST, but is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Properties Service instead.

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
scriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", ii);
```

ref: [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: The problem is Google has deprecated Script Properties. That's the thing we're stuck with. Please read :[Class ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties) Do you know any other options?

Comment: @Br.Sayan  ScriptProperties is deprecated. not the properties service :) `getScriptProperties` is the replacement for `ScriptProperties`. read the link above

Comment: @Sujay : you have written ‘userProperties‘, it's probably a typo...?

Comment: @SujayPhadke : Thank you!...You're right...`Properties Service` is the replacement.