# Google app scripts: Does auto-save adds to trigger time or total trigger time?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have a script which gets triggered every 15 mins and total time to run the script is 2 mins. That means for normal consumer google account, I can run the scripts 30 times for total trigger time quota of 60 mins.
My question is, most of the time in script-run time is Google autosaving the changes. Does that times gets added to trigger time or NOT?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not added. You may verify it in the Execution transcript. You may refer with this [documentation](https://medium.com/@dkodr/how-to-keep-track-of-google-apps-scripts-total-execution-time-c46e9d1dfdef) to count the total daily execution time of a whole Google Apps Script project. Check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/exceeded-maximum-execution-time-in-google-apps-script) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @abielita

Comment: Does my comment help?